# Syntax error at CREATE TRIGGER query

Tags: postgresql, triggers, syntax-error

I have this code, to add trigger for a View in my postgresql database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION changeCityProc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $changeCity$
    BEGIN
    UPDATE vvs.tb_company SET city = "LAL" WHERE cardpresso.cardinfo.tb_company_city = vvs.tb_company.city;
    RETURN null;
    END;
$changeCity$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;




CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON
      cardpresso.cardinfo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changeCityProc();
```

pgAdmin says "syntax error at or near "INSTEAD""

Comment: The correct syntax is `INSTEAD OF`, but I would expect the error to be at `UPDATE` instead of `INSTEAD`.

Comment: Maybe the docs could help a little: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: INSTEAD OF is there. missed it when posting code, sry

Comment: Please, update the code to match exactly the code with the error.

Comment: Do you have column `"LAL"` in your tables? If not, then it's better to use single quotes for string literal.

Comment: no, it was random string to check. Changed it, but it did not help

Comment: @GordonLinoff if i change Instead of to After or Before it says cardpresso.cardinfo is not a table ( it is view actually)

Comment: @AlexanderCapone: "Triggers that are specified to fire INSTEAD OF the trigger event must be marked FOR EACH ROW, and can only be defined on views. BEFORE and AFTER triggers on a view must be marked as FOR EACH STATEMENT." [Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify this.  First, the two schemas.

```
CREATE SCHEMA cardpresso;
CREATE SCHEMA vvs;
```

Next, the simplest possible table.

```
CREATE TABLE vvs.tb_company
(
  city character varying(25)
);
INSERT INTO vvs.tb_company VALUES ('foo');
```

And a fairly useless view.

```
CREATE VIEW cardpresso.cardinfo AS
  SELECT 'test' as tb_company_city UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orem' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wibble'
;
```

Simplify the function. **Warning**: This will destructively update the table. Be careful if you copy stuff from this function into something headed for production.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION changecityproc()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    UPDATE vvs.tb_company SET city = 'bar';
    RETURN null;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Finally, the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
  INSTEAD OF UPDATE
  ON cardpresso.cardinfo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE changecityproc();
```

Now, if we update the view, we'd expect all the rows in vvs.tb_company to change to 'bar'.

```
select * from vvs.tb_company;
```

```
city
--
foo
```

```
update cardpresso.cardinfo
set tb_company_city = 'wibble';

select * from vvs.tb_company;
```

```
city
--
bar
```

So it *looks* like the problem is in the UPDATE statement of your function.

```
UPDATE vvs.tb_company SET city = "LAL" 
WHERE cardpresso.cardinfo.tb_company_city = vvs.tb_company.city;
```

I'm not certain what you intended that statement to do, but it's not valid in PostgreSQL, regardless of whether "LAL" is supposed to be a column name or a string literal. As a string literal, 'LAL', it will raise an error.

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cardinfo"
LINE 2:     WHERE cardpresso.cardinfo.tb_company_city = vvs.tb_compa...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have small question: i have to add Where OLD.cty='someconstantvalue' to change only those who has someconstantvalue

So i have to chnage FOR EACH ROW as well ? please tell to what if yes:)

Comment: No, you don't need to change FOR EACH ROW to FOR EACH STATEMENT as long as you're still using an "instead of" trigger. Test your SQL update statement in a SQL window (psql, pgAdmin, etc) before you try to use it in a trigger function. When you create a trigger function, PostgreSQL doesn't try to determine whether the SQL statement is valid; it trusts *you* to do that.

Comment: UPDATE vvs.tb_company SET city = 'surprice' where OLD.city='foo';
in table i got 5 foo cities and 5 bar cities
after trigger works i got 10 suprise cities, when i wanted to have 5 surprises and 5 foo...how do i do it?

Comment: If you wanted to keep your 5 "foo" cities, you shouldn't have used `where OLD.city='foo'`. But your update statement shouldn't have set *all* values to 'surprise' in any case.  It *sounds* like you wanted to do something more like `UPDATE vvs.tb_company SET city = 'surprise' where OLD.city='bar';`.

Comment: yes, sorry, i meant that.
in result of this function, i get 10 surprise after Updating view either way...

Comment: Well, yes, that's the whole point of my answer, and that's why there's a boldface **Warning** in the middle of it. The SQL UPDATE statement in *my* trigger function updates every row. I couldn't use the SQL statement in *your* trigger function, because it doesn't make sense; PostgreSQL can't execute it. (See error message at the end of my answer.)

Comment: okay.. so last question:
how do i change only that company rows which had value of city = 'foo'

Comment: There's no way to answer that without knowing what update statement you want to execute against the view, and what you want the trigger to do instead of that update.